# How to have multiply lines in a case statement in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, recursion

I'm coding in Haskell for the first time, and I'm having trouble with case statements.

```
points = do
  pts <- try(readLn :: IO Int) :: IO (Either SomeException Int)
  case pts of
    Left ex -> putStrLn "Please enter a number."
    Right val -> return pts
```

This code is for reading an integer from user input, and checking to make sure it is indeed an int. The issue I'm having is with the `Left ex` case. What I want to do is, if there's an exception, to print the line `"Please enter a number."` and then run the points function again. The issue is that I can't figure out how to call points within the `Left ex` case, as it interferes with the print statement. Any guidance?

Comment: Also, is there just an easier way to do this, like a built in readInt function? I wasn't finding one, but it would make sense for that to exist

Comment: “it would make sense for that to exist” – not really. Parsing text input from an interactive terminal prompt is cumbersome, inconvenient and unsafe. Back in the 80s you often had nothing better, but nowadays you should either just read standardized configuration files like JSON, or have some kind of graphical interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `do` notation, which allows to glue several `IO` (or another monad's) actions in order, like you're already doing in the body of `points` itself:

```
points = do
  pts <- try(readLn :: IO Int) :: IO (Either SomeException Int)
  case pts of
    Left ex -> do
      putStrLn "Please enter a number."
      points
    Right val -> return pts
```

Alternatively, you could do what the `do` notation does under the hood, and use the `>>=` operator, which is what glues two `IO` actions in order:

```
points = do
  pts <- try(readLn :: IO Int) :: IO (Either SomeException Int)
  case pts of
    Left ex -> putStrLn "Please enter a number." >>= \_ -> points
    Right val -> return pts
```

Note that the `\_ ->` bit ignores the first action's return value. So you can use the `>>` operator, which does the same thing as `>>=`, but throws away the first action's result:

```
points = do
  pts <- try(readLn :: IO Int) :: IO (Either SomeException Int)
  case pts of
    Left ex -> putStrLn "Please enter a number." >> points
    Right val -> return pts
```